# ThreadPool with speed execution control

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, threadpool

I need proccess several lines from a database (can be millions) in parallel in c#. The processing is quite quick (50 or 150ms/line) but I can not know this speed before runtime as it depends on hardware/network.

The ThreadPool or the newer TaskParallelLibrary seems to be what feets my needs as I am new to threading and want to get the most efficient way to process the data.

However these methods does not provide a way to control the speed execution of my tasks (lines/minute) : I want to be able to set a maximum speed limit for the processing or run it full speed.

Please note that setting the number of thread of the ThreadPool/TaskFactory does not provide sufficient accuracy for my needs as I would like to be able to set a speed limit below the 'one thread speed'.

Using a custom sheduler for the TPL seems to be a way to do that, but I did not find a way to implement it.

Furthermore, I'm worried about the efficiency cost that would take such a setup.

Could you provide me a way or advices how to achieve this work ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: WHY do you want to limit the speed? What kind of processing are you trying to do? Are you keeping the connection open (shudder!)? The best place to process database records is the database itself. A proper SQL statement or stored procedure (that DOESN'T use cursors) is the most efficient way to process data. The RDBMS will process the data in parallel as needed. Most RDBMSs also have their own ways to limit resources if needed. Remember, data warehouses and star schemas can handle billions of rows event in mediocre hardware and have been doing so for decades

Comment: I am writing an email sending queue. I need to have control on the speed for specific needs related to mailing, the is a mandatory feature of the software I intent to write. The processing is mainly CPU usage (template processing). Full SQL processing is not an option, based on the kind of thing I wish to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TPL provides a convenient programming abstraction on top of the Thread Pool.  I would always select TPL when that is an option.

If you wish to throttle the total processing speed, there's nothing built-in that would support that.

You can measure the total processing speed as you proceed through the file and regulate speed by introducing (non-spinning) delays in each thread.  The size of the delay can be dynamically adjusted in your code based on observed processing speed.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, can you explain what is a non-blocking delay ? Would you recommend to watch the number of active threads and adjust the delay or set a fixed number of thread to prevent extra calculation ?

Comment: Non-blocking delay can be as simple as Thread.Sleep(numberOfMilliseconds).  If the workload is largely CPU bound, I would have one thread read data and write it into a `BlockingCollection<T>` and use N threads to process items off of the `BlockingCollection<T>`.  I would initially set N to the number of CPU cores and measure performance.  I would adjust the throughput by delaying threads rather than adding or removing threads, once an optimal number of threads for your use case is determined.

Comment: @EricJ.: Since when is Thread.Sleep "non blocking"? The thread that is sent to sleep is blocked, all others not. Did you mean that?

Comment: @igrimpe: Thanks for pointing that out.  I meant non-spinning (edited answer).  Non-blocking would be even better as the thread would not even be scheduled (and would not consume a thread pool slot) but the programming of that is slightly more complex unless using the new async/await mechanism.

Comment: Look at Task.Delay for your non blocking sleep needs

Comment: Thank you, i will look at all these things

Comment: Eric J., do you have an example of how implement the non-blocking option ?. Putting a delay in each task does work but as you said, not scheduling the task until is has to actually do work seems a cleaner way.

Comment: @Aestek: If you're trying to stop/start threads in response to current throughput, keep in mind that you will have a limited number of threads to play with to get the desired throughput. What if a single thread is fast enough for the desired throughput?  Do you want to stop all threads and then start a thread (repeatedly) to achieve the desired average throughput?  A self-tuning per-thread delay will make more efficient use of resources.  I do not have an example handy, though I have done this before quite successfully in production code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing the advantage of limiting a speed, but I suggest you look into limiting max degree of parallalism of the operation. That can be done via [MaxDegreeOfParallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in the ParalleForEach options property as the code works over the *disparate* lines of data. That way you can control the slots, for lack of a better term, which can be expanded or subtracted depending on the criteria which you are working under.

Here is an example using the [ConcurrentBag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd381779%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to process lines of disperate data and to use 2 parallel tasks.

```
   var myLines = new List<string> { "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Omega" };

   var stringResult = new ConcurrentBag<string>();

   ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions();

   parallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2;

   Parallel.ForEach( myLines, parallelOptions, line =>
   {
      if (line.Contains( "e" ))
         stringResult.Add( line );

   } );

   Console.WriteLine( string.Join( " | ", stringResult ) );
   // Outputs Beta | Omega
```

Note that parallel options also has a [TaskScheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.taskscheduler%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property which you can refine more of the processing. Finally for more control, maybe you want to cancel the processing when a specific threshold is reached? If so look into [CancellationToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.cancellationtoken%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property to exit the process early.

Comment: As I said, the number of threads does not provide sufficient accuracy for my needs. However, ConcurrentBag seems interesting for what I am trying to do. Implementing a custom TaskScheduler seems to be a clean and efficient way to do this, but i don't see how to implement that and the number of custom TaskScheduler example around the web is not quite high.